# Binary Data from server is missing bytes when using Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, typed-arrays

I have been working on this for days now with no avail :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to download a file as a typed array using this method below:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true); //This is the path to my file 
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
 var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; 
 var array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer ); //This is the array I retrieve from my file
};

oReq.send(null);
```

When I do this with all assets being on my computer's hard drive it works perfectly and I'll get a response back that looks like this (this is just example data):

```
array[0] = 10;
array[1] = 15;
array[2] = 20;
array[3] = 17;
array[4] = 18;
array[5] = 23;
array[6] = 25;
array[7] = 12;
array[8] = 2;
array[9] = 10;
...
```

However when I upload everything to the server I get a result that looks like this:

```
array[0] = 10;
array[1] = 15;
array[2] = 20;
array[3] = 17;
array[4] = 18;
array[5] = 25;  //This number is missing from above, it should be 23
array[6] = 12;
array[7] = 2;
array[8] = 10;
array[9] = 18;
...
```

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this problem. Clearing the cache, turning gzip on and off, testing it with different devices (ie loading it on a phone and a computer), but nothing has been of any help so far.

What strikes me as odd is that the same numbers are consistently wrong every time. So I don't think they are getting "lost" over the network. Also when I test it with a different server I get different numbers that drop. So it seems like every server drops a different set of numbers.

Does anyone know why this is and could you lead me toward a direction to help fix the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: are you **actually** dealing with .png's?

Comment: Technically no, I'm dealing with a blob file that contains binary data. However I can rename the extension of the blob file to whatever I want and it still works on the local side. Would this make a difference?

Comment: no, I was just wondering - not sure where I was headed with that question ... have you tried fetch? ... `fetch('/myfile.png').then(res=>res.arrayBuffer()).then(ab=>new Uint8Array(ab)).then(u => console.log(u))` ... does that also "miss" bytes?

Comment: also, check the developer tools network tab - is the `Content-Length` header changing too?

Comment: Regarding your first question, I apologize I've never seen the "fetch" api before and I couldn't get it working from your provided code. However I did check the "content-length" and it does change depending on the file type. Which is very interesting. For example when the file is a .png it is 1,714,496 bytes, when it is just a blob file (no extension) it is 1,713,636 bytes.

Comment: What browser are you using

Comment: Every browser acts the same way, I am using chrome and firefox mainly, but they all drop the same numbers.

Comment: They both have fetch so that's odd. What errors in the console when you use fetch. I strongly suspect server side problem if different browsers behave the same

Comment: SyntaxError: illegal character

...then(res=>res.arrayBuffer()).then(ab=>n‌​ew Uint8Array(ab)).then(u => console.log

Comment: A typo on your part perhaps. Is the request firing

Comment: oops, typo on my part?

Comment: I just got the fetch request to fire, and from what I can tell the numbers are all correct. However the "net" developer tab tells me that the file only download 1800 bytes, which is much smaller than the actual file size. Still though whatever number of the array I choose to display it is the same as the local file. Sorry I didn't know this would be so confusing lol, maybe there's a work around I can use with this approach? I need more browser support than firefox and chrome however.

Comment: is there a Content-Length header

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if there is one or not, Firebug tells me the download fize size, but I don't see a header.  This is the url link I'm testing on if it helps  http://amightywind.com/zip/sample7/

Comment: firebug? developer tools network tab is better in my opinion

Comment: Oh okay I see a header using chromes dev tools. Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:public, max-age=1209600
CF-Cache-Status:MISS
CF-RAY:2dbcd0fe39142e93-MIA
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1714496
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Fri, 02 Sep 2016 00:23:58 GMT
ETag:"1a2940-53b7b3a0ea046"
Expires:Fri, 16 Sep 2016 00:23:58 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 02 Sep 2016 00:15:24 GMT
Server:cloudflare-nginx
Set-Cookie:__cfduid=de82e63e2ff374d4b4deae2121c16e5aa1472775838; expires=Sat, 02-Sep-17 00:23:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.amightywind.com; HttpOnly
Vary:Accept-Encodin

Comment: somehow I got "crap" added to my fetch command I posted in an earlier comment - was doing my head in ... `fetch('/myfile.png').then(res => res.arrayBuffer()).then(ab => new Uint8Array(ab)).then(u => console.log(u))`

Comment: `Content-Length:1714496` - is that correct? if you run the fetch command, is the resulting array the same length?

Comment: Yes 1714496 is the correct length and I get the correct length when using the fetch command. However I also get the same length when I use the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: and data is still missing?

Comment: Yes it is, but I'm actually seeing something new. The data from the server is missing depending on the extension of the file. For example if I save it as a txt file the length is 1713636, however if I save it as a jpg it is the right length. And most of the jpg file is correct, but it has some "re arranged" parts in the middle. Could the server be adding custom stuff to the file like a header/meta data that is interfering with reading the raw binary array?

Comment: no idea about what your server is doing, but it must be doing something ... when you say "save", do you mean just rename? are the files with the different extensions still the same length on the server filesystem?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: something in your server is messing things up (that's a technical term :p ) - but I can't for the life of me even begin to think what is happening - from the response headers, you're running `nginx` - I've used `nginx` for ever and never witnessed any such issues

Comment: Okay thank you for your time and help, I'll keep searching and if I find the solution I will post it as a response to my question to help any others stuck in my situation. I also have a server from godaddy that is doing similar stuff but in different places, so I thought maybe this would be a common problem but I guess not. Well back to the drawing board it seems :-)

Comment: One thing you may want to look at is  "character encoding" - though it's a shot in the dark seeing as you're dealing with binary data

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I figured out what the problem was and posted an answer to my question explaining what had happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out... wow was this an interesting experience.

It turns out the FTP client I was using (FileZilla) has a setting that automatically tries to detect a files datatype and make necessary adjustments to it in order to display properly across all OS systems.

It is a documented behavior that can be read about here:
https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Data_Type

When I turned this behavior off (switched it from auto to binary under that "transfer" - "transfer-type" tabs) everything is working again as expected.

I want to thank Jaromanda X so much for his willingness to help. His answers gave me the insight I needed to play around with these settings. I hope this will help others in the future who have the same problem!

Comment: what doesn't make sense is that it got rid of a byte with the value 23! I could understand it if there was a 13 missing, would've suggested some sort of "end of line" shenanigans ... but 23?

Comment: I don't understand it either, but yeah throughout the file it was removing random values and even moving them around. I don't claim to understand it, all I know is that I changed the ftp setting and it's all working now. So yeah, hopefully this helps someone :D